# if...then to concat SQL queries, equivalent in LINQ - VB NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, linq, if-statement

I have simply code:

```
 Dim query as string = "SELECT id, red, yel, gre FROM table WHERE"
 if a then query=query + " red=true OR"
 if b then query=query + " yel=true OR"
 if c then query=query + " gre=true"
 if right(query,2)="OR" then query=left(query,len(query)-3)
```

How to make equivalent in LINQ ?

Update:
(I need OR operator not AND like many other examples on the site)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If a,b and c are Boolean variables the below code works:

```
Dim result = dbContext.Table();
result = result.Where(Function(r) (a And r.red) Or (b And r.yel) Or (c And r.gre));
result = result.ToList();
```

But if you mean a,b and c are logic clauses and you are using .net method like `.ToString()` in them you have to change the code like below:

```
Dim result = dbContext.Table().ToList();
result = result.Where(Function(r) (a And r.red) Or (b And r.yel) Or (c And r.gre));
```

Because .net methods can't run on dbcontext, first call `ToList()` to transmit data and after that you can use all .Net method on transmited data.

Comment: Does this connect "WHERE" with AND operators not OR?

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer

Comment: a,b,c are logic clause. How it will be look in VB NET?

Comment: just syntax changes